# How can I search, highlight and click with xdotool in Chrome?

Tags: chrome, xdotool

I need to click a string of text hundreds of times, and the text moves around. Let's say that the string is FOO.

This is what I have:

```
xdotool key ctrl+f
xdotool key f 
xdotool key o
xdotool key o
xdotool key Escape
xdotool key Return
```

All that happens is that I jump to a different application, appears to be the most recently opened one.
This is in a bash script, if that matters.

What's wrong with my commands? Help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your script. Adding a `sleep 3` between each `xdotool` line  should help to see what happens after each key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The script is executed when the user presses Alt-Z, so that must be unset first. With the line `xdotool keyup alt+z` added to the start of script, it works!